# Git log colorify GPG signature verification status

Tags: git, gpg-signature

Git log pretty-format has placeholder `%G?`

> ```
>        o   %G?: show "G" for a good (valid) signature, "B" for a bad signature,
>            "U" for a good signature with unknown validity, "X" for a good
>            signature that has expired, "Y" for a good signature made by an
>            expired key, "R" for a good signature made by a revoked key, "E" if
>            the signature cannot be checked (e.g. missing key) and "N" for no
>            signature
> ```

I would like to print `G` in green colour and `B` in red colour. How can I do that?

It also would be nice to replace `G` with `good` and `B` with `bad`.

<sub>Please do not suggest to use third-party cmds like *sed* or *awk*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't provide a way to make pretty formats conditional, so there is no way to do what you want with a plain Git command.  You would need to use some other tool to modify the output, which is what the Git developers would suggest in this case.